# Rails engine gem should or should not explicitly load helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm wondering if a Rails engine gem, such as [React on Rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/), should be using this line of code to explicitly load the helper:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do 
  include ReactOnRailsHelper 
end
```

This is definitely not needed for normal Rails application use of the gem. However, some users have reported this as an issue.

Any opinions?

Here's the specific issue reported:

https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/issues/385#issuecomment-209964034

This is how the react-rails gem does it (not a Rails Engine):

https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/blob/master/lib/react/rails/railtie.rb#L42-L44

Comment: Hi - this is an interesting question... but unfortunately it's not really a good fit for Stack Overflow. It will no doubt spark an interesting and possibly lively discussion... and here we prefer questions that have a single "right answer". The reason being that in the past we allowed discussion topics, and some of them led to flame wars that tore apart our community... so now we just don't allow them anymore. :( it's a great question... just not the best for here.

Comment: Why is there no right or wrong answer for this one? Either it's recommended or not.

Comment: Some people will recommend it... some people will not recommend it... different people have different ideas about whether something is recommended or not... so there is no one right answer because it's based on different people's opinions.